# Jekyll Liquid Check if array contains object with specific values

Tags: jekyll, liquid

I have an array that looks like this:
`[0, 1, 2, 3, {'key': 'test', 'id': 0}]`

Now I'm assigning a key to a variable `key` and an id to the variable `id` and I'd like to check if the array contains an object with said key and id.

I tried the following:
`{% if arr contains {'key': key, 'id': id} %}`
but this always turns out false.

How could I check for this properly?

Comment: From the liquid docs: "*`contains` can only search strings. You cannot use it to check for an object in an array of objects.*"  But if you are in the context of Jekyll, maybe you could utilize the `find` filter somehow? https://jekyllrb.com/docs/liquid/filters/

Comment: @derpirscher Do you have an idea how I could utilize the `find` filter? Looking at the documentation, it requires a key and a value, but I'm only trying to find a value, said value being the object... I could theoretically iterate through the entire array and check each element if it's an object, but as I'm working with several large arrays, this seems rather clunky...

Comment: It's probably easier to create your own filter for this - it could return true or false. That way you could write this logic with Ruby which will be much easier to debug.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check for the size of the resulting array using the **where** filter.

The **where** filter takes two arguments:

- the property to filter on.
- the value to match.

You can chain multiple where filters together to filter on multiple properties, for example:

```
{% assign filteredArray = arr | where: 'key', key | where: 'id', id %}
{% if filteredArray.size > 0 %}
   <!-- The array contains an object with key and id or not (size 0) -->
{% endif %}
```

The [Jekyll documentation page about filters](https://jekyllrb.com/docs/liquid/filters/) is not really telling you more though.